# Sum different columns with pandas. Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a code to concat 2 dataframes with pandas and sum the totals. The problem is I don't want to sum `'Fecha'`and `'hours'` because as you can see in the example I have a row with all values of that and I want a empty row there!

```
df = pd.read_csv('a_AR.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('a_US.csv')

frames = [df1, df]
result = pd.concat(frames)
result = result.sort_values(by=['Fecha','hours'])

del result['eCPM']
del result['Importe_a_pagar_a_medio']

result.loc['Total']= result.sum()

result.to_csv('a_AR-US_Days_hours.csv', index=False)

os.remove('a_US.csv')
os.remove('a_AR.csv')
```

Example results:

```
Fecha,hours,impressions,revenue
22/01/2018,23hs,1666,0.73
22/01/2018,23hs,67,0.02
00hs00hs01hs01hs02hs02hs03hs03...,01/01/201801/01/201801/01/201801/01...,1733,0.75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without `Fecha` and `hours` columns for filtering:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Fecha','hours'])
```

Another more dynamic solution with [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for select all `numeric` columns:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns

df.loc['Total']= df[cols].sum()
```